# Uncaught TypeError: d3.interpolateRdYlGn is not a function

Tags: d3.js

I am having issues with the d3 package d3-scale-chromatic while trying to create a color scale.

In my index.html I have:

```
<script src="scripts/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/treemap_v5.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
```

In my js file I have:

```
var color2 = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateRdYlGn);
console.log(color2(0.5));
```

And the error I get is:

```
d3.v4.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: t is not a function
    at n (d3.v4.min.js:4)
    at treemap_v5.js:13
```

Based on all the examples I have found online, it seems like this should work.  I also tried sourcing the d3 libraries from cdnjs and nothing changed.

Does anyone know what's going wrong here?

Comment: You have a problem referencing `d3-scale-chromatic` somewhere, because the code works: https://jsfiddle.net/3ugtteg9/

Comment: What Gerardo Furtado said, for example, It should work with this `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v0.3.min.js"></script>`. Check your reference.

Comment: I'm an idiot.  What's not accurate in my post is that I load my file treemap_v5.js BEFORE I load d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js.  So that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, it is easy to miss :) (we missed that too)

Comment: Me too, I thought that that JS was just another library...